# Module export function that post on RabbitMQ queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq

I have a nodeJS server and want to set up a connection and export function to post messages to queue from the js file.

```js
const amqp = require("amqplib");
const url = process.env.RABBITMQ_SERVER;

let channel = null;

amqp.connect(url, (e, conn) =>
  conn.createChannel((e, ch) => {
    channel = ch;
  })
);

module.exports = publishToQueue = (
  data,
  queueName = process.env.RABBITMQ_QUEUE
) => channel.sendToQueue(queueName, new Buffer.from(data));

process.on("exit", code => {
  ch.close();
  console.log("closing rabbitmq channel");
});
```

But when I try to import and use it, I've got empty object {}

```js
hooks: {
    beforeCreate (instance) {
        console.log(amqp)
        amqp(JSON.stringify(instance.toJSON()))
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
thanks HosseinAbha's answer, i've ended up with creating a class and set up connection in constuctor

```
const amqp = require("amqplib");
const url = process.env.RABBITMQ_SERVER;

class RABBITMQ {
    constructor () {
        this.connection = null
        this.channel = null
        this.connect()
    }
    async connect () {
        try {
            this.connection = await amqp.connect(url)
            this.channel = await this.connection.createChannel()
            await this.channel.assertQueue(process.env.RABBITMQ_QUEUE)
            await this.channel.bindQueue(process.env.RABBITMQ_QUEUE, process.env.RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE)
            await this.channel.assertExchange(process.env.RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE, 'fanout', { durable: true })
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err)
            throw new Error('Connection failed')
        }
    }
    async postData (data) {
        if (!this.connection) await this.connect()
        try {
            this.channel.publish(process.env.RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE, `${data.type}.${data.event_type}`, new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)))
        } catch (err){
            console.error(err) 
        }
    }
}
module.exports = new RABBITMQ()
```

Comment: What are `hooks` and `beforeCreate` method? What framework/library are you using? How do you import the first module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `publishToQueue` function should return a promise and it should connect to rabbitMQ before doing anything. Your function should be something like this:

```
const connectToChannel = async () => {
  try {
    let connection = await amqp.connect(url)
    return connection.createChannel()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('failed to create amqp channel: ', e)
  }
}

let channel;
module.exports = publishToQueue = async (
 data,
 queueName = process.env.RABBITMQ_QUEUE
) => {
  if (channel == null) {
     channel = await connectToChannel();
  }
  return channel.sendToQueue(queueName, Buffer.from(data));
}
```

You also don't need to instantiate the Buffer and `Buffer.from` is enough.